# Converting 2D integer matrix to binary tree

Tags: algorithm, matrix, data-structures, tree, binary-tree

I have a 2D integer matrix and I have to convert it into a tree, to perform matrix multiplication. Is there any way to do that.

Matrix:

```
   [[1 2 1]
   [2 1 2]
   [2 2 2]]
```

The matrix can square or rectangular.
I am trying to design an algorithm for getting the result of matrix multiplication, with better time complexity. Since most of the operations in binary tree are of 0(h).

Comment: Why can't you use the matrix for performing matrix multiplication? How does a matrix "convert" into a tree?

Comment: You can modify the code in following link for your use case : https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/construct-tree-from-ancestor-matrix/

Comment: It is not at all obvious what you're asking for. Can you give us more information?

Comment: I am trying to design an algorithm for getting the result of matrix multiplication, with better time complexity. @JimMischel

Comment: And you expect to do that by creating a binary tree from the matrix? You should edit your question to explain your idea.

Comment: You might find this interesting: [Wikipedia: Computational complexity of matrix multiplication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computational_complexity_of_matrix_multiplication)